# How to get random selected values from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having a directory that contains an N number of key and values and I want to iterate only 4 random and unique keys and values and then need to check the highest and lowest key and values among 4 entries then find the subtraction.

let consider:

```
    main_dict = {"a":144,"c":55,"d":33,"e":65,"f":44,"s":344,"r":90,"t":33}
   
    random_key_and_values = 4
```

the new dictionary will be

```
    new_dict = {"c":55,"f":44,"r":90,"d":33}
```

with the new dictionary, I need the subtraction of the highest and lowest values of new_dict values.

```
    output  = 57
```

Comment: Can you share what have you tried?

Comment: I will quickly share

Comment: Something like [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) is what you need

Comment: Please accept an answer using the grey checkmark on the left of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tino's answer may work, but it can be done without third-party libraries, just with builtins:

```py
import random

main_dict = {"a" : 144, "c" : 55, "d" : 33, "e" : 65, "f" : 44, "s" : 344, "r" : 90, "t" : 33}
rand_choice_len = 4
new_dict = dict(random.choices(list(main_dict.items()), k=rand_choice_len))
output = max(new_dict.values()) - min(new_dict.values())
print(new_dict, "difference of highest and lowest is:", output)
```

References:
[`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)
[`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)
[`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)
[`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

Comment: You can use `dict(...)` instead of `{k: v for k, v in ...}` - the `dict` constructor accepts an iterable of pairs.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks, weird I didn't encounter that when searching for "python dict from items" …

Answer (score 0):

The code below should be what you are looking for. A couple loops and np.random.choice

```
import numpy as np

main_dict = {"a":144,"c":55,"d":33,"e":65,"f":44,"s":344,"r":90,"t":33}
   
random_key_and_values = 4

new_dict = { key : main_dict[key] for key in np.random.choice(np.array(list(main_dict.keys())),random_key_and_values)}

diff = np.array(list(new_dict.values())).max() - np.array(list(new_dict.values())).min()

print(diff)
```

Comment: Using numpy can be handy sometimes, but sometimes, it can be an overkill ...

Comment: why is that? Never really understood this "overkill" idea. Numpy is rather standard in every python distribution, why not using it?